# Selenium Find Element by XPATH with a slightly changing XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, dynamic

I have a script that loops through a table and uses this line to identify the table:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-tabs-0-buildDetails-panel"]/span/div/ui-table/div/div[3]/table/tbody')
```

However, every time it saves an input and goes to run the next loop on a refreshed page the number after "tabs" changes and it isn't iterative, so it could be anything.

So I am looking for something like this in psuedo-code:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-tabs-*variable*-buildDetails-panel"]/span/div/ui-table/div/div[3]/table/tbody')
```

Where the * variable * is the something could be a different number every run through.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you share the url or html?

Answer (score 1):

How about just ignoring the variable like this:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id,"ui-tabs-") and contains(@id,"-buildDetails-panel")]/span/div/ui-table/div/div[3]/table/tbody')
```

Is that of some use to you?

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you very much.